# pure css for styling an element that does not contain something

Tags: css

I'm wondering if it's possible to apply css to something that does not contain something.

For example,

I have a component that can either contain a `h1` or an `h1` and `span`:

```
<div class="block">
 <h1> title </h1>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="block">
  <h1> title </h1>
  <span> sub </span>
</div>
```

I know of the selected `:not`, but I believe this will affect all elements except the `:not`

If I wanted to do something like:

```
.block { display: flex }
.block:DoesNotContain(span) { align-items: center }
```

Is there such a way to do so?

Comment: I really don't think that's possible with pure CSS only.

Comment: I would say no. but you can solve your problem programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, it's quite nice and simple:

We can define a baseline and instead of "`DoesNotContain`", include everything if it *does* contain we can remove via the `:has` selector

```
.block { 
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
.block:has(span) {
   align-items: normal;
}
```

It's not exactly the same but it achieves the same results.

Comment: Yes, it is a way to do this.